# Highlight the text that Matches the Regex

Tags: perl

When I use `ag` or `rg` to select a text, it highlight the selected text.

```
$ echo "First HTML appeared, then CSS, then JavaScript" | rg -N 'HTML|php|CSS|Java(Script)?' 
$ echo "First HTML appeared, then CSS, then JavaScript" | ag --nonumbers 'HTML|php|CSS|Java(Script)?'
```

But when I use Perl, it does not highlight the matching text.

```
$ echo "First HTML appeared, then CSS, then JavaScript" | perl -ne '/HTML|php|CSS|Java(Script)?/ and print'
```

[image]

I tried the following:

```
echo "First HTML appeared, then CSS, then JavaScript" | perl -ne 'use Term::ANSIColor qw(:constants);/HTML|php|CSS|Java(Script)?/ and print RED, $_'

echo "First HTML appeared, then CSS, then JavaScript" | perl -ne 'use Term::ANSIColor;/HTML|php|CSS|Java(Script)?/ and print color("red"), $_'
```

It changes the color of the whole text and not the selected text.

How can I highlight the text that matches the Regex when using Perl to search?

Comment: You have to surround **found** string with [ESC sequence](https://askubuntu.com/questions/558280/changing-colour-of-text-and-background-of-terminal) of some color supported by your terminal.

Comment: To color a word in a sentence, I think not so simply.  That module -- which I use all the time -- colors the given string; it can't pick it apart.  So you'd have to do it by hand, word (by space) by word  and it'd be messy.  Like `@p = split /(\s+)/;  for (@p) { /HTML|php|CSS|Java(Script)?/ ? print RED $_, RESET : print }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You switch the colour to red, print the entire line, then leave the colour red. No good.

You want to print non-matching text, switch the color to red, print matching text, reset the colour, and repeat as needed.

Since `RED` and `RESET` just return strings that are interpreted by the terminal, we could achieve the desired effect by inserting those strings into the appropriate locations of the string to print by replacing

```perl
/HTML|php|CSS|Java(Script)?/ and print RED, $_
```

with

```perl
s/HTML|php|CSS|Java(?:Script)?/RED.$&.RESET/eg; print
```

We can write the shell command as follows:

```sh
perl -MTerm::ANSIColor=RED,RESET -pe's/HTML|php|CSS|Java(?:Script)?/RED.$&.RESET/eg'
```

We can remove the dependency as follows:

```sh
perl -pe'
   BEGIN { $RED="\e[31m"; $RESET="\e[0m" }
   s/HTML|php|CSS|Java(?:Script)?/$RED$&RESET/g
'
```

(The line breaks can be left in or removed.)

We could even inline the strings at the cost of readability, maintainability, etc.

```sh
perl -pe's/HTML|php|CSS|Java(?:Script)?/\e[31m$&\e[0m/g'
```

Answer (score 2):

It won't be so simple to color a word or a few inside a string with more text, I'm afraid.<sup>†</sup>  The good module colors a string given to it and it can't pick parts out of it, for all I know.

So it would have to be done by hand, word (by space) by word and it's a bit messy.  Like

```
echo "First HTML appeared, then CSS, then JavaScript" |
perl -MTerm::ANSIColor=:constants -wne'
    @p = split /([,.\-\s+])/;  
    for (@p) { /HTML|php|CSS|Java(Script)?/ ? print RED $_, RESET : print }'
```

This demo works correctly on the given string but I'm pretty sure that one can find cases that will break it given that it parses the string in that `split`, which isn't a simple thing to do in general.

The capturing `()` in the separator pattern in [split](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) make it so that those separators are returned as well in the result list, so that we can reconstruct the text with all it had.  I include some punctuation there, along with spaces, but that is something to look at carefully and extend as suitable.

This "parsing game" can be avoided by splitting on the regex pattern for the wanted words

```
perl -MTerm::ANSIColor=:constants -wne'
    BEGIN { $re = qr/HTML|php|CSS|Java(?:Script)?/ };
    for (split /($re)/) { /$re/ ? print RED $_, RESET : print }'
```

The regex is first stored in a variable to avoid silly repetition of a possibly gruesome expression

This still suffers from starting a regex engine on every word, what can be felt for a long text.

---

<sup>†</sup> Well, it is -- insert suitable ANSI escapes, using regex. See other answers here for that approach

Comment: Re "*It won't be so simple to color a word or a few inside a string with more text*", Actually, it is. See the other answers :)

Comment: You could even have achieved it using `@p = split /(HTML|php|CSS|Java(?:Script)?)/;`

Comment: @ikegami "_Actually, it is_" -- yeah, I realized that later :).  Got drawn into the module and didn't think regex (at all).  But, the right approach for this has been posted so all is well.  I'll edit this (thanks for the note) and  leave it, as it may be useful for some other uses/reasons... (?)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @PolarBear the solution that is working for me is:

```
echo "First HTML appeared, then CSS, then JavaScript" | perl -pe 's/(HTML|php|CSS|Java(Script)?)/\e[31m\e[1m\e[4m$1\e[0m/g'
```